# Stack independent c/c++ bluetooth api?

Tags: c++, c, windows, bluetooth, desktop

I wanted to know if there is any stack independent C/C++ bluetooth api for windows (XP, Vista, 7, x86 and x64).

My target is to create a connection and send/receive some time critical data over bluetooth.

My researches gave me the following options and there disadvantage for this task:

- Windows Sockets for Bluetooth
  Only works with microsoft bluetooth stack
- Using the COM port (CreateFile/ReadFile/...)
  Slower than the socket option and the user has to connect to the device first.
- Use stack dependent API
  This would require to detect the used stack and create read/write functions for every stack. Very time consuming and I don't know if it is even possible to support all stacks
- Writing a KMDF driver
  I thought about writing a function driver to talk directly with the bluetooth HCI driver which should be stack independent. This would be very time consuming because I would have to read the whole bluetooth spec, or is there an API for the HCI commands?

I know that there is also a commercial sdk from btframework.com which supports most (or all) bluetooth stacks, but I need a freeware option.

Please tell me if there are any other options for this task.
If there aren't any, could you tell me which options you would prefer and why?
Is it okay to use Windows Sockets and ignore the other bluetooth stacks?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just an aside, Bluetooth should never be used for time critical data unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: Dhaivat, why not? Assuming good FECs and hashing, it's very unlikely that anything will be corrupted.

Comment: This page linked to an academic paper that says Bluetooth is not suitable for time-critical applications: http://nettoyeur.noisepages.com/2011/01/midi-over-bluetooth-part-ii-latency-and-jitter/

Comment: Thanks for the information. My project requires Bluetooth so I have no other options :)

Comment: `never` ... `unless you have to` made me laugh :) Also, indeed my supposed [HIFI Voiis A2DP receiver](http://reviews.cnet.com/cell-phone-and-smart/voiis-stereo-wireless-music/1707-6448_7-32571549.html) brings back memories of old vinyl players: wow and slow pitch wobbling! It's quite unbearable with some music and it happens when there is physical interference (like Wifi traffic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess one option would be to use C++/CLI to interface with my managed Bluetooth library 32feet.NET which supports most of the stacks on Windows.  http://32feet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you :D I've already read about the 32feet.NET lib (and about the bluecove for java too) in other stackoverflow questions. I sadly ignored it because it wasn't for C/C++. I never thought that something like C++/CLI would even exist. :D I currently have to write a proof of concept (using the socket option), but I will try your solution as soon as possible, thanks again :)

Comment: Good.  If you try the C++/CLI route let me know how it goes. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've been successfully using this [library](http://www.btframework.com/bt.htm) it is called WCL but it is not free. With this you can connect through SPP without requiring to create a virtual COM port.

While their documentation is not very good, they provide some good demo code that you may want to try.

It supports the Microsoft, Toshiba, Widcomm and Bluesoleil stacks and there is a native C++ implementation (as well as a .NET one).

Comment: No I've no relationship with those guys. I just spent a lot of time searching for such a librairy that I think it is helpful to share this information. I can erase my posts if it becomes such an annoyment for you.