# Bluetooth library cross platform in c ++

Tags: c++, list, bluetooth, device

is there any  library cross platform written in c++ that permit to know the list of devices that are  connected to  this  pc?

Comment: Duplicate of [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928571/stack-independent-c-c-bluetooth-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Multi-OS Bluetooth library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513205/is-there-a-multi-os-bluetooth-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Qt5.2 you can use Qt bluetooth library  : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-module.html

Comment: Qt5 Bluetooth "cross platform" support is limited to only Android, Linux, and Blackberry 10.  Qt has no Bluetooth support planned for Windows, OSX, or iOS.

Comment: As of May 2023 Qt bluetooth support is very poor - buggy and poorly documented.  Even the examples don't run properly.

Comment: @TSG It was buggy back then too

Answer (score 2):

Here are some additional libraries, none of which are really production-ready:

- https://github.com/OpenBluetoothToolbox/SimpleBLE (previously https://github.com/kdewald/nativeble)
- https://github.com/iotile/baBLE
- https://github.com/mbientlab/Warble

Is anybody aware of any other possibly in-progress cross-platform bluetooth libraries?

Comment: https://github.com/Agamnentzar/bluetooth-serial-port

Answer (score 1):

Qt5.2 and Qt5.4 Bluetooth cross platform support is *** * very * *** limited.

Qt 5.4 Bluetooth support is implemented only for Android and Linux (BlueZ 4.x/5.x).  I guess BlackBerry 10 is included too since it is QNX based.

There is no mention of planned Qt Bluetooth support for either Windows, OSX, or iOS.

See: [Qt Bluetooth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html)

-Ed